# How does a magnetic field interact?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I want to understand the way magnetic attraction/repulsion works. Yes, I know there is a field but what do we really mean by that?

When it comes to light I understand that if I shine a torch towards an object, photons travel at the speed of light and impact the object creating different energy states in the constituent atoms which then reflect more photons. These photons entering my eyes is how **seeing** happens.

What is happening in the case of a magnetic field? It's not like the atoms have a brain. Something must be making them interact with the field. But how can anything be repelled/attracted without there being a physical interaction? How does the pull and push of a magnetic field occur?

I suppose this question can be asked of all kinds of electromagnetic attraction too. From my limited understanding, I know in the case of gravity, the whole space-time is warped which causes objects to move towards each other. But what would be the analogous mechanism in magnetic or electromagnetic attraction?

Am I not understanding something very obvious? I am surprised I never questioned this before and that no physics teacher I have had even raised this question.

Comment: light, electric forces, magnetic forces can travel thru a vacuum .... there is no matter in the vacuum to help the forces travel ..... therefore science proposes the concept of a field that carries these forces, it fills all space, it is between every atom, and fills the universe. No scientist knows exactly how the field works ..... they just know very much about how it behaves. The field is a concept .... a very successful and helpful concept.

Comment: After asking this question here, I saw a video from Feynman in which he's talking about similar stuff. He also hinted that beyond a point, we don't really know. It is just absurd that we take this for granted that something fills up our world and we can observe its effect and create accurate mathematical models but we don't truly know what it is.

Comment: it's not absurd, no one takes it for granted ..... man/science has spent millions/billions to dig deeper .... the field concept has revealed many things ..... but some things we will probably never know ..... or maybe we never need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is happening in the case of a magnetic field? It's not like the atoms have a brain. Something must be making them interact with the field.

For the sake of simplicity, I'll just talk about electrons.
Electrons are not only electric charges, but also magnetic dipoles. Just as only separated electrons produce a macroscopic electric field, only aligned dipoles of electrons form a macroscopic magnetic field.

Another way to generate a magnetic field is to move electrons through a conductor coil. This is called electro->magnetic induction.

> But how can anything be repelled/attracted without there being a physical interaction? How does the pull and push of a magnetic field occur?

A magnetic field generated in this way acts on any magnetic dipole in its neighbourhood, i.e. also on the magnetic dipoles of the electrons in the atom, and more or less aligns them.

The force field is real, we have proven it by experiment. It is represented by field lines, also known as lines of force. The internal mechanism along the force field has not yet been considered and requires considerations analogous to those that Maxwell made in his considerations of EM induction in the macroscopic range.

> I suppose this question can be asked of all kinds of electromagnetic attraction too. From my limited understanding, I know in the case of gravity, the whole space-time is warped which causes objects to move towards each other. But what would be the analogous mechanism in magnetic or electromagnetic attraction?

Neither for gravitation nor for electrical and magnetic interactions have elementary particles been introduced that are sufficient for a model to describe these processes. Just like the hypothetical graviton (which is currently useless because there is no model of gravitational interaction), particles must also be introduced for electric and magnetic interactions and the photon. The only certainty is that there must be two particles.

Answer (score 4):

The key word here is "field": everywhere there is an electric and magnetic field produced by electric and magnetic sources (and actually they are two sides of the same electromagnetic field). So the charge or magnetic object is affected by the field near it, even though the sources may be far away. The physical interaction is always local to the thing affected, but the field connects everything.

The way a charged object feels the force from the field is given by the [Lorentz force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), and if it is not moving it generates an electric field by [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law). If it is moving it also generates a magnetic field. However, there is no counterpart to a simple charged object for magnetic fields (technically, there are no magnetic monopoles): magnetic fields always come from charges that are flowing in loops or spinning. This means that the sources are always dipoles (have a north and south magnetic pole) or some more complicated structure. Correspondingly, when there is an outside magnetic field affecting them, it will try to push the flowing charges or turn their spin which is why two magnets will repel or attract each other.

Why do we get magnets? The simple answer is that the atoms of the material have some unpaired electrons that spin that are aligned, producing a noticeable field (most materials have electrons that align their spin so that the net effect is zero).

The really deep question is "why does stuff respond to this field?" In a sense it is just the definition of the field: [you could say that the field is what imparts a certain change in momentum on particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Relativistic_form_of_the_Lorentz_force), and then define [the equations for what the field is doing elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Current_3-form,_dual_current_1-form). [One can motivate this by mathematical simplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Classical_electrodynamics_as_the_curvature_of_a_line_bundle), but it goes very deep.

How this interaction happens is typically described like here in terms of a classical field. [One can do a quantum mechanics description in terms of quantum interactions between charged particles and photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) (quantum electrodynamics), but it is much less simple to explain. It can be viewed as particles emitting and receiving photons, but the actual mathematical framework is way more involved since those photons are mostly not actual photons but "virtual" photons that are not localized. Usually it makes more sense to calculate what the fields are doing directly, but the formulas determining this can be derived from the [Feynman diagrams of possible particle-photon interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#Feynman_diagrams).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll be honest, the equations seem to be beyond my level right now. However, even if I understood them, they're not the answer I was looking for. Okay, so when an electron repels another electron, how do they know they should move away from each other? Are they emitting some kind of particles that hit the other electrons? I know this is what a field represents but while it is an accurate model, it feels like a "field" is a virtual concept we have created that explains this behaviour. But there must be a true physical concept as well, right? What is happening physically?

Comment: @s_a94248 - In modern physics it is the other way around: fields are the "real" things, and particles are seen as excitations of the fields. So it is not so much particles knowingly bouncing off each other as field patterns spread out across space and time interacting in ways that look like there are two electrons repelling each other.

Comment: @s_a94248 If I understand you correctly, you insist that there must be a mechanism of interaction between charges that concretises the field concept. I have made an attempt to create such a model here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320171902_Are_photons_composed_particles or here: https://www.academia.edu/11805855/Are_photons_composed_particles     You will probably have to register. If you don't want to do that, write to me.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity at first was explained as an action at a distance. The Newton theory fitted so well that the same idea was used by Coulomb for electrostatic and even by Ampere in its first theory of the force of attraction between conducting wires.

But magnetic attraction is not suitable for that approach. For example, the experiment of a wire in direction North-South above a compass. When the DC current is turned on, the needle deflects *from the alignment* with the wire!

The idea of a magnetic field around the wire, that adds to the Earth magnetic field, leading to a net field *to which the needle aligns* can better explain the stuff.

The Faraday idea of scattering iron fillings on a surface surely helped to convince people to visualize what is that magnetic field.